# Order columns alphabetically in dataframe Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe like this:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(C = [1,2,3],
               A = [1,1,1], 
               B = [3,2,1])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ C      A      B     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      1      3
   2 │     2      1      2
   3 │     3      1      1
```

I would like to alphabetically order these columns which would be of course: A,B and C. How can we do this in a dataframe `Julia`? It could be more than 3 columns. In R we could use the `order` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method I came up with is:

```
julia> select(df, sort(propertynames(df)))
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      1
   2 │     1      2      2
   3 │     1      1      3
```

and to mutate `df` into ordered form:

```
select!(df, sort(propertynames(df)))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `names` with `sortperm`

```
julia> df[:, sortperm(names(df))]
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      1
   2 │     1      2      2
   3 │     1      1      3
```